# Django using multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model called `FieldMap` which is used throughout my project. I decided recently that the physical database for this model will exist on another machine (other than the `default`).

So I now have two databases setup in my settings: `default` and `dev`.

I can use both databases like this:

```
FieldMap.objects.using('dev/default').all()
```

Because my project has already been written, I dont want to have to go through code and make the changes every time I read/write from this model.

So after all that, I was wondering if there is a way to tell a model which database to read/write from by default?

Comment: What is your motivation for using a second database?

Comment: We have a dev and live server. The FieldMap data needs to be kept identical on both

Comment: Perhaps you should have asked: What is the best way to keep my development database in sync with my production database?

Comment: I didnt want to put any more stress on the live server and figured there was no point in keeping them in sync constantly as it would be redundant. Also having researched this a little bit, I became curious as to whether this was possible.

Answer (score 3):

Consider writing a custom database router that decides the database to use on the fly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers